# Can i use the Logical Operator "or" in combination with strings?

Tags: python, string, logical-operators

Im reading a txt-file, and counting how many times specific words are in the file. For example I want to know how many times "ABC" and "DEF" are there. My first idea was:

```
for line in open:
    if "ABC" or "DEF" in line:
        x=x+1
```

the result is x= 33... but thats wrong.
Using:

```
for line in open:
    if "ABC" in line:
        x=x+1
    if "DEF" in line:
        x=x+1
```

the result is 8! and thats correct.

Why the first example doesnt work?

Comment: ouh yeah, that looks similar, sry for the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"ABC" or "DEF" in line
```

is evaluated as

```
("ABC") or ("DEF" in line)
```

Since `"ABC"` is a truthy value, the if condition will be satisfied **always**. You can fix this problem like this

```
if "ABC" in line or "DEF" in line:
```

which will be evaluated like

```
("ABC" in line) or ("DEF" in line)
```

So, if the line had either `ABC` or `DEF`, the condition will be satisfied.

If the number of valid words to be checked is large, it would be inconvenient to write a lengthy `if` condition. Instead of that, you should write that condition, with [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function, like this

```
valid_words = ["ABC", "DEF"]
...
if any(word in line for word in valid_words):
```

**Suggestions:**

1. Avoid using `open` as a variable name, as it will shadow the builtin [`open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) function
2. When you are dealing with files, make sure that you [close the opened files properly or prefer to use `with` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.close).

Comment: Or distribute the relational operator.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks :) I included that in the answer

Comment: thx a lot! Im not using "open" as variable name in my programm, I just used it here, but thx for the advise. And yeah, in my program Im closing my file too :D Im going to use the any function. thanks a lot :D